# How do I get an integer value using ODBC?

Tags: c++, odbc

I'm trying to get an int value from one table from my database. To deal this using ODBC, I've written:

```
std::string strRequete = "SELECT MIN(idO) FROM dbo.Opo WHERE l = 'x' AND b = '' AND t = 'r'";
std::wstring strwRequete(strRequete.begin(), strRequete.end());
retcode = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR*)strwRequete.c_str(), SQL_NTS);

SQLINTEGER cbTestStrId;
SQLINTEGER sziIdO;
SQLGetData(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_LONG, &sziIdO, 1, &cbTestStrId);
```

But, using this haven't solve my problem. I'm getting LONG value as return that I couldn't understand the meaning instead of getting `86`.

How do I fix this, please?

Comment: Why did you declare an array of 100 SQLINTEGER's?  Isn't it just one integer you're interested in?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, you're right, I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

In the `SQLGetData()` function call, use `SQL_C_DEFAULT` instead `SQL_C_LONG` for the `TargetType` parameter (the third one).

If `TargetType` is `SQL_C_DEFAULT`, the driver selects the default C data type based on the SQL data type of the source, which in your case should be `int`.

If the value is not defined as `int` in the SQL data source, you can use `SQLINTEGER` as the `TargetType` for casting to `int`.

Additionally, the last argument in the `SQLGetData()` should be of type `SQLLEN`, so change the variable `cbTestStrId` accordingly. Test its value after execution, because it can notify you about errors, if it matches one of the following:

- `The length of the data available to return`
- `SQL_NO_TOTAL`
- `SQL_NULL_DATA`

In such case, your `sziIdO` should not considered valid. Check you SQL for errors, and make sure it yields a valid response on your SQL server.

For more information about the topic, read [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: would you please write a snippet code explaining this ? Because when I've replaced `SQL_C_LONG` with `SQL_C_DEFAULT`. I'm still getting a LONG output but with a different value.

Comment: Maybe your DB has `LONG` defined as the type. Try with `SQLINTEGER` instead  `SQL_C_DEFAULT`.

Comment: No, you've guessed it right. It's as datatype `int`. When I try `SQLINTEGER` I'm getting an error with the debugger.

Comment: Well, since `SQLINTEGER` is defined as `typedef long int` I am not sure what exactly are you expecting to get? Is it possible you are getting the correct result? What number are you getting?

Comment: with that posted request string I've to get `86` as return value.

Comment: And what do you get when you run it?

Comment: Updated the answer with more useful data.